# Applications and examples of vector valued functions

Tags: functions, vectors, book-recommendation

Learning about vector valued functions, [there is this page](https://mathinsight.org/derivative_multivariable_examples) I like with not overly technical, short explanations and exercises.

The particular topic is vector valued functions. Is there any resource with nice examples of applications you'd recommend so I could train this knowledge?

More than a book, it'd be nice if you know something short, to the point like the resource I'm including, but anything is fine!

In particular, when I saw this vector function:
$$\vec{f}(x,y,z) = (x^2\,y^2z,y + \sin(z))$$

I've no idea what something like this could be useful for, and can't visualize it either, I don't know if there is any software for such a thing.

Comment: A big source of vector-valued functions is in the context of physics. When a physicist talks about the "electric field of a point charge" or "magnetic field of a current-carrying wire", they're talking about particular vector-valued functions.

Comment: thanks @Semiclassical will get into it then